# Exception "path not found" in access vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have the following code that throws an exception "Path not found".

```
Dim myfso As New FileSystemObject
Set myfso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim myoFile As Object 
Set myoFile = myfso.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\myname\dropbox_folder\Dropbox\dropboxpath.txt")
myoFile.WriteLine "C:\Users\myname\dropbox_folder\Dropbox\"
myoFile.Close
Set myfso = Nothing
Set myoFile = Nothing

Dim strContents As String
Dim myfso1 As New FileSystemObject
Set myfso1 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim myoFile1 As Object
Dim mypath As String

Set myoFile1 = myfso1.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\myname\dropbox_folder\Dropbox\dropboxpath.txt", ForReading)
strContents = myoFile1.ReadAll
myoFile1.Close


Dim fso, oFolder, oSubfolder, oFile, queue As Collection

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set queue = New Collection

queue.Add fso.GetFolder(strContents)
```

This last command throws the exception: Path not found. But the path exist "C:\Users\myname\dropbox_folder\Dropbox\" and this is positive lets not argue about that.

The strange is that if you point the mouse over the variable you see this:
"C:\Users\myname\dropbox_folder\Dropbox\
without the second ". That is a bit strange for me.
Furthermore, if I run the previous command

queue.Add fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\myname\dropbox_folder\Dropbox\")

the code executes smoothly.

What is the problem in your opinion?

Comment: The variable I am refearing to is strContents

Comment: it has to do with the textfile adding a ` " delimiter` to the beginning of the file when you write the file ... you have to account for that somehow ... a quick and easy way maybe `strContents = Replace(myoFile1.ReadAll,"""","")`

Comment: also, you don't need 2 instances of `FileSystemObject` one is enough, you can keep working with it over and over. Same for `myoFile`, unless you need to work with 2 files simultaneously.

Comment: nop, the same problem occurs.

Comment: I have also tried to manipulate the string created with:
    myoFile.WriteLine "C:\Users\myname\dropbox_folder\Dropbox\"

to produce the exact string needed: "C:\Users\myname\dropbox_folder\Dropbox\", with
    myoFile.WriteLine "C:\Users\myname\dropbox_folder\Dropbox\""""
Looking at the variable in debug mode, confirmed the correct string, but still I get the same error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to:

```
myoFile.Write "C:\Users\myname\dropbox_folder\Dropbox\"
```

because `WriteLine` appends a `VbCrLf` (`\r\n`) to the file. When you subsequently  `ReadAll` you end up with `VbCrLf` on the end of the path, invalidating it. (The CrLf is not displayed in the single line tool-tip but manifests as the absent closing `"`)

Comment: Yes, that solved my problem...I knew that but I didn't notice the command was writeline. 
Thank you very much.

Comment: @MikePerakis - please check off as answered if it solves your problem.